# Python Mysqldb returning '\x01' for bit values

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, mysql-python

Im using Mysqldb with Python(2.7) to return a bunch of values form a Mysql database with a charset latin1.

The mysql database has values of type bit(1) when these are returned they look like this  '\x01'

Decimal values return like this Decimal('0E-8')

They rest of the values and types are fine.

Sample Database resultset:

{'test': '\x01', 'currency': u'bla',  'balance': Decimal('0E-8'),  'first': u'John'}

This is how im connecting to the database:
self.con = MySQLdb.connect(host = conn['host'], user = conn['user'], passwd=conn['passwd'], db=conn['db'], charset=conn['charset'],port = int(conn['port']) if 'port' in conn else 3306)

I would like the bit(1) values to be return as either True or False.
I have looked around and I think it might be to do MySQLdb.converters.conversions but im not sure how to implement this. Any ideas would be great.
Thanks

And I don't have access to change the types in the DB.

Answer (score 10):

try:

```
orig_conv = MySQLdb.converters.conversions
#Adding support for bit data type
orig_conv[FIELD_TYPE.BIT] = lambda data: data == '\x01'

passing this into my connection.
MySQLdb.connect(conv=orig_conv)
```

using "orig_conv[FIELD_TYPE.BIT] = bool" just returned everything as true for me

Comment: This is the ACTUAL answer!  The current accepted answer is wrong and makes all BIT fields True regardless of the actual value in the database.

Comment: This works with pymysql as well. You could simplify with "orig_conv[FIELD_TYPE.BIT] = ord".

Comment: Hi guys... Some idea in order to adapt this solution for google cloud python sdk for Mysql?

Answer (score 5):

Talking to developers of MySQL internals, they all say the BIT data type is broken and riddled with bugs.

Example: [Why you should not use BIT columns in MySQL](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/04/11/bit-values-in-mysql/) by Baron Schwartz, co-author of *High Performance MySQL*.

So I'd suggest using TINYINT and store either 0 or 1 to represent a boolean. You won't waste any space, because the size of a BIT column rounds up to the nearest whole byte anyway.

MySQL even has a data type alias `BOOL`. When you use it, it is mapped to `TINYINT(1)` (though the 1 doesn't affect anything).

---

If you can't change the data type, then you can map it to an integer in your SQL query:

MySQL uses 1 or 0 for boolean values, so you can just do this:

```
SELECT (test=B'1') AS test, currency, balance, first FROM ...
```

Or you can be more verbose:

```
SELECT IF(test=B'1', 1, 0) AS test, currency, balance, first FROM ...
```

Or you can be completely SQL compliant:

```
SELECT CASE test=B'1' WHEN true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS test, currency, balance, first FROM ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but unfortunately I can't change the types in he database its outside of my domain.

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out:
So had to dig a little in the Mysqldb package.

```
orig_conv = MySQLdb.converters.conversions
#Adding support for bit data type
orig_conv[FIELD_TYPE.BIT] = bool

passing this into my connection.
MySQLdb.connect(conv=orig_conv)
```

The `FIELD_TYPE` can be found in `MySQLdb.constants` and can be imported this way

```
from MySQLdb.constants import FIELD_TYPE
```

Comment: actually this caused issues too - all rows returned true, we didnt get runtime errors but the data is wrong :s

Comment: This answer is wrong, see the correct answer by "RhysC" below

Answer (score 0):

```
from pymysql import converters
converions = converters.conversions
converions[pymysql.FIELD_TYPE.BIT] = lambda x: '0' if x == '\x00' else '1'
db = pymysql.connect(mysql_host, mysql_user, mysql_password, mysql_db, 3306,charset='utf8',conv=converions)
```